# Is there an effective workaround for the intel i965 bug affecting libEGL?

Tags: linux, graphics, intel-graphics

I've been trying to get a functional development environment set up on my laptop for a couple of days now and I've hit a brick wall in setting up *cocos2d-x*.
I managed to get everything to compile, but when I run the `cpp-tests` to confirm that everything's working, I find that everything's not working:

It produces a misdrawn window that inherits the image behind it when it is created, and produces the following error message:

> libEGL warning: failed to create a pipe screen for i965

I've found a fair amount of chatter about instances of this bug by searching around, and a couple of claimed work-arounds, but I can't get any of them to work for me.
It seems to be a majorly contentious point whether the bug is in libEGL, libglfw, or the i965 linux driver itself.
The bug seems to be fairly old (mentions occuring from 2014-2016) and it seems that some people consider it already resolved, which is frustrating because I've updated everything obvious.

If anyone could help me find a working fix for Mint 17 Cinnamon, I would greatly appreciate it.

Edit:
One offered workaround has supposedly been incorporated into libglfw as of 3.2.1 as described in [this thread](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/issues/205) on the LWJGL github site, but I learned (perhaps wrongly) that this was a candidate workaround from [this other thread](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4347) on the libGDX github site.  I compiled libglfw from the repository, as well as libGDX, make installed as root, no improvement.

Comment: "a couple of claimed work-arounds" — could you [edit] in at least references to what you have already tried, to keep us from going down the same misleading paths?